# Formating window values with jq

Tags: linux, jq

I would like to take the json output of window values from a program. The output of it currently is:

```
[
  3067,
  584
]
[
  764,
  487
]
```

But I need it to be formatted like: `3067,584 764x487`. How would I go about doing this using jq or other commands?

I'm not very experienced with jq and json formatting in general, so I'm not really sure where to start. I have tried looking this up but am still not really sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that does not `--slurp` would be using `input` for every other array:

```bash
jq -r 'join(",")+" "+(input|join("x"))'
```

```
3067,584 764x487
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rn3W-Df7P6G)

Answer (score 1):

If your input is a stream of JSON arrays, you could use jq's `-s`/`--slurp` command-line option.  Join the first array with comma, the second array with "x"; and finally join both strings with a space:

```
$ jq -sr '[(.[0]|join(",")), (.[1]|join("x"))] | join(" ")' <<JSON
[
  3067,
  584
]
[
  764,
  487
]
JSON
3067,584 764x487
```

Alternatively, simply use string interpolation:

```
jq -sr '"\(.[0][0]),\(.[0][1]) \(.[1][0])x\(.[1][1])"'
```